# Defining own destructor although class derives from QObject?

Tags: c++, qt

Let's have a class `Test` and a class `AnotherClass`. Both derive from QObject.

Test.h:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Test(QObject* parent);
    ~Test();

private:
    AnotherClass* other;
};

class AnotherClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    AnotherClass(QObject* parent);
    ~AnotherClass();
};
```

Test.cpp:

```
Test::Test(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) 
{
    other = new AnotherClass(this);
}

Test::~Test()
{
    delete other;
}
```

`other` should be automatically destroyed when the `Test`-instance is destroyed because `Test` is the parent of `other`, right?

- Now should I delete `other` by myself in `~Test()` or does it leave the program in an undefined stage because it tries to delete the same object twice?
- What is the correct approach here?

Comment: yours destructors shoud be virtual.

Comment: @KoVadim - Because QObject has virtual destructor, his destructors are implicitly virtual already..

Comment: why don't you add `delete this` in your code after deleting `other` ??? Are QObjects automatically deleted without explicit `delete` word even if they have no parents?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*QObjects* organize themselves in object trees. When you create a *QObject* with another object as parent, the object will automatically add itself to the parent's *children()* list. The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its destructor. See [Object Trees & Ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) for more information.

Because you pass *this* pointer of *Test* object to *AnotherClass* constructor it means that you use *Test* object as parent of *AnotherClass*. Thus deleting *Test* object deletes also its child and **you don't need to explicitly delete** *other*.

However, in this case **explicit deletion in the destructor doesn't cause double deletion because it causes unregistration** from the parent's children() list.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that you have to make the destructor `virtual`, the Qt documentation says:

> When `QObject`s are created on the heap (i.e., created with `new`), a tree
>   can be constructed from them in any order, and later, the objects in
>   the tree can be destroyed in any order. When any `QObject` in the tree
>   is deleted, if the object has a parent, the destructor automatically
>   removes the object from its parent. If the object has children, the
>   destructor automatically deletes each child. No `QObject` is deleted
>   twice, regardless of the order of destruction.

So you can `delete` the `other` class explicitly, but you don't have to. Either approach should work without double `delete`s.

By the way, you could also make the `AnotherClass` a simple member of `Test` instead of a pointer.

Comment: You shouldn't make it a simple member, because QObjects aren't copyable/.assignable.

Comment: Sorry, virtual destructor. This has been pointed out already, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors